# Script for Paypal

Tags: paypal

I want to use just one add to cart paypal button for my website and substitute the product value using php and select.

```
<select name="select_stuff" id="select_stuff">
      <option value="0011" >Prod1</option>
      <option value="0012" >Prod2</option>
</select>


<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd2" value="_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="business2" value="info@xxxx">
      <input type="hidden" name="lc2" value="IT">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name2" value="Prod1">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number2" value="0011">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount2" value="20.00">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code2" value="EUR">
      <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype2" value="products">
      <input type="hidden" name="no_note2" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" name="shipping2" value="0.00">
      <input type="hidden" name="add2" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="bn2" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_SM.gif:NonHostedGuest">
      <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/IT/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit2" alt="PayPal - Il sistema di pagamento online pi&ugrave; facile e sicuro!">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

For example from the combox I select the product 0011 then I reload the page so that the form above will be filled by the values for adding to the cart for 0011 and so on...
Then user can click add to cart.

i will put an switch case in order to set the variables for the form based on value of select (0011, 0012..) . What do think? Is it a good a approach? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not a good approach. Since you'll be sending the amounts to be charged to PayPal clear-as-day in the source of your pages, leading possible manipulation of your prices.

You could fix this by using the BMCreateButton API to create a 'hosted button', where the amounts are securely stored with PayPal. But if you're going to be using any API's already, you may as well start using PayPal Express Checkout.

Express Checkout is based on three API calls; SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

1. SetExpressCheckout sets up the payment and returns a token
2. You redirect the buyer to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN-HERE, where TOKEN-HERE is the token you received earlier
3. After the buyer has agreed to the payment, he is returned back to your site.
4. You can call GetExpressCheckoutDetails and supply the token as a parameter to get the PAYERID of the buyer.
5. Call DoExpressCheckoutPayment with the token and PAYERID supplied to finalize the payment

You can find additional documentation for Express Checkout at https://www.x.com/community/ppx/documentation#ec as well as the SDK's and sample code at https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks#NVP